# Shopify API: Adding an item to cart without redirect

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, shopping-cart, shopify

Is there any way to submit an add to cart POST request without any sort of page redirection whatsoever? Changing return_to to "back" reloads the page, which I don't want to do. I want to add the item to the cart and use a jQuery notification to alert the client, without any type of redirection/reloading. The notification part works fine, I just can't figure out how to override the redirect. Sorry if some of the things I said make no sense, I'm new to this stuff. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the AJAX API. Details are here: http://wiki.shopify.com/Ajax_API Check out the `Shopify.addItem` function in the jQuery wrapper demo page: http://mayert-douglas4935.myshopify.com/pages/api

Comment: Ok, I did: http://cdn.shopify.com/s/shopify/api.jquery.js?925eb20b1451cb9124f04e01f65ac40bbcf78ba1  That's their jQuery API. I went down to the "POST to /cart/add.js" section, and you can see for yourself what's there. There's nothing about reloading the page or redirecting to another page, I suspect that's something /cart/add.js does and the only way to control its behavior is through setting the "return_to" field parameter. I was wondering if there was any value that would stop the page from reloading.

Comment: Are you returning false from the form submit or button click handler?